# EF Runtime error in WHERE query: Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

When `ToList` is applied always this exception is thrown

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: querySource

```
var memberExpression = (navigationPropertyPath.Body as MemberExpression);
var returnType = memberExpression.Member is MethodInfo? ((MethodInfo)memberExpression.Member).ReturnType: ((PropertyInfo)memberExpression.Member).PropertyType;                
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TEntity), "s");
var fieldParameter = Expression.Parameter(returnType.GetTypeInfo().GetGenericArguments()[0], "field");
var anyPredicate = Expression.Lambda(
          Expression.NotEqual(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(fieldParameter, "Column"),
            Expression.Constant(true)
          ),
          fieldParameter);
var fieldCondition = Expression.Call(
          typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(x=>x.Name == "Any").Skip(1).Take(1).First().MakeGenericMethod(new[] { fieldParameter.Type }),
          memberExpression,
          anyPredicate);
// You can use the fieldCondition in your combinator,
// the following is just to complete the example
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(fieldCondition, parameter);
var list= source.Where(predicate).ToList(); ;
```

This code creates a custom standard `WHERE` query and tries to convert the result to a list.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I improved the formatting of the code and clarified the question.

Comment: Thanks for your added question.

Comment: Can you add some information about `navigationPropertyPath.Body` and about the wanted resulting expression? It looks like you want to do something with the parameter `s`, but you don't, as far as I can see.

Comment: navigationPropertyPath is s=>s.ListOfNavigationProperty and it turns it s.List.

Comment: Just to be sure... what happens when you statically construct the predicate for testing? `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate = s => s.ListOfNavigationProperty.Any(field => field.Column != true);` Does it work without error then?